# After submiting the jsf page valueChangeListener is not calling

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

`h:selectOneMenu` is not calling the listener method in the backing bean.

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="catSoc1"
                                value="#{product.itemIdSelected}"
                                valueChangeListener="#{product.itemChangeListener1}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{product.items}" var="catprod"
                                    itemLabel="#{catprod.name}" itemValue="#{catprod.id}" />
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="opl11 sco12 imgId pageImgId sco13 opl2" />
```

backing bean method is:

```
public void itemChangeListener1(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        selectedItem = (String) event.getNewValue();
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            item = productUploadService.getItemOnId(selectedItem);
            if (item != null) {
                setTotalPages(item.getTotalpages());
            }
        } 

}
```

Comment: Maybe the value did not actually change? Did you run your application in development mode?

Comment: but if i go to another tab and come back, the valuechangeevent fires :(

Comment: So if you click outside the input e.g. into the browser url location and focus it does not work? Tried other browsers? This sounds strange. The valueChange will only fire if the value on the server side changes and that only happens in your case when the ajax is fired. Are you sure you need a valuechangelistener?